# expression for "the small letters" of the contract, as in the nuances and discalimers that will bite you?

Tags: expressions

Looking for an equivalent of the Hebrew expression "the small letters of the contract" - as in the small disclaimers / minutia / nuances of the contract that if you won't put on glasses and read will bite you afterwards? e.g. "what? you didn't read the small letters of your live organ donation certificate?!"

Comment: The ***fine print***

Comment: Or, in British English, **small print**.